# How do i call variable c from def cal_fun()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, calendar, nameerror, nested-function

I am trying to call the variable c in the below code. It says the cal is not defined

```py
def pay_cal():

    def cal_fun():
        t = Toplevel()
        global cal
        cal = Calendar(t, year=2019, month=6, day=1, foreground='Blue', background='White', selectmode='day')
        cal.pack()

    c = cal.get_date

    sub_win =Tk()
    sub_win.geometry('400x500+600+100')
    sub_win.title('Payout Calculator')

    l1 = Button(sub_win, text= 'Check-In Date:', command= cal_fun)
    chck_in_date = Label(sub_win, textvariable= c )
    l1.grid(row=1)
    chck_in_date.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple things wrong with your code. For starters, you define `c` as `cal.get_date` when `cal` hasn't even been created yet.

Next you pass `c` as a `textvariable` for a `label` widget. It will not raise any error, but it will not get updated either - what you need is a `StringVar` object.

You also lack the mechanism to update the textvariable upon calendar selection. Even your original code is fixed, the date will only update once upon execution.

Here's how you can make everything work:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar #I assume you are using tkcalendar

def pay_cal():

    def cal_fun():
        t = Toplevel()
        global cal
        cal = Calendar(t, year=2019, month=6, day=1, foreground='Blue', background='White', selectmode='day')
        cal.pack()
        cal.bind("<<CalendarSelected>>",lambda e: c.set(cal.get_date())) #make use of the virtual event to dynamically update the text variable c

    sub_win = Tk()
    sub_win.geometry('400x500+600+100')
    sub_win.title('Payout Calculator')
    c = StringVar() #create a stringvar here - note that you can only create it after the creation of a TK instance

    l1 = Button(sub_win, text= 'Check-In Date:', command= cal_fun)
    chck_in_date = Label(sub_win, textvariable=c)
    l1.grid(row=1)
    chck_in_date.grid(row=1, column=2)
    sub_win.mainloop()

pay_cal()
```

Lastly I noticed you use `sub_win` as a variable name for this function - which means you might have a `main_win` something else. It is generally not advised to use multiple instance of `Tk` - if you need additional windows, just use `Toplevel`.

Comment: If it helped, consider accepting the answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: i have a tiny issue, which i have mentioned below with the code, could you help?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post as a new one, not add as an answer. With that being said, I cannot understand any of your new code or what you are trying to achieve.